# Select IDs with two or more entries greater than amount

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL, and I'm struggling with a homework problem:

1. Get the name and initials of each player who has incurred two or more penalties of more than $40. **Hint: use subquery that has an aggregate**

I can get MySQL to show me the amounts more than $40, but I can't seem to get it to only show the players that have two or more penalties. I've watched a ton of tutorials and read forums online, and after two hours, I'm finally waiving the white flag and asking for help on this one.

Here is the table:

```
Paymentno, playerno, payment_date, amount
'1','6','1980-12-08','100.00'
'2','44','1981-05-05','75.00'
'3','27','1983-09-10','100.00'
'4','104','1984-12-08','50.00'
'5','44','1980-12-08','25.00'
'6','8','1980-12-08','25.00'
'7','44','1982-12-30','30.00'
'8','27','1984-11-12','75.00'
```

Here is my code thus far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT playerno
FROM penalties 
WHERE amount > 40 IN (SELECT playerno
            FROM penalties
            GROUP BY playerno
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT playerno) > 1);
```

And here it was it returns:

```
Playerno
'6'
'44'
'27'
'104'
'8'
```

It should only return playerno 27, and I've tried all sorts of different variations. Can someone please point me in the right direction on this one? I appreciate your help and guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned about; **use of a subquery with an aggregate**;

Here is a solution.

```
SELECT playerno
FROM penalties
WHERE playerno IN (
  SELECT playerno
  FROM penalties
  WHERE amount > 40
  GROUP BY playerno
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
group by playerno;
```

I have tested it and here is a [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e915c/1) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is great, and it's right in line with what we've learned thus far. How does the count know to count playerno using the '*'? I've only seen the * after the select statement to mean ALL.

Comment: In MYSQL, we have different aggregate functions. Those can be used with select statements or with Having clause.
Here is a list of such aggregare functions.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html

Comment: Also,
Please feel free to accept any answer above; which addresses your query / problem.

That can earn you `scholar` badge on stackoverflow

Comment: The COUNT(*) function returns the number of rows in a dataset. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html

Answer (score 1):

We can use conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT playerno
FROM penalties
GROUP BY playerno
HAVING SUM(amount > 40) >= 2;
```

If you must solve this using a subquery, I can suggest the following:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT playerno
FROM penalties p1
WHERE amount > 40 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM penalties p2
              WHERE p2.playerno = p1.playerno AND
                    p2.paymentno <> p1.paymentno AND
                    p2.amount > 40);
```

The second query finds all players having a penalty greater than 40 for whom we can *also* find a second record from a different occasion where the penalty also happens to be more than 40.

Comment: Holy crow! That worked! THANK YOU! I'm hesitant to use that for this assignment though as the instructions clearly state that I'm supposed to use a subquery with an aggregate. Any thoughts on how I can correct my subquery to get it to work?

Comment: I have added a subquery version which does not use any aggregation.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate the help! As I really am interested in learning the material, I do have some followup questions if you have the time/patience. I will of course look these up too, but it's always beneficial to learn from a professional.

Comment: Hit enter too soon! In your subquery, is the p2.playerno = p1.playerno the same thing as a self join? I just recently learned about self joins, and this looks like it's doing the same thing. Also, I've not learned EXISTS yet, but it looks like it allows me to give multiple conditions-- does this give multiple conditions for the original WHERE or the subquery WHERE, or am I totally off base here? If this is too much of a newbie question then I can look through my textbook/YouTube tutorials. Again, I very much appreciate your help!